# Vba script to get number of columns in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a script that gets the total amount of columns used in a table and saves the number as a Number. I dont want to select the data.

```
Sub AddHeaders()

Dim NumColumns As Number

NumberColumns = ???
```

Comment: Do you want the numbers of columns used within a **Sheet** or within a **Table** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
intCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

will give you the index of the last column with any content or specific formatting inside one of its cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This will give you the last column used in row 1, change the 1 to whatever row you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely over the top answer - will give you the details of all separate regions in your workbook (a region being separated by a blank row and column).

You didn't state if there'd be more than one table on a sheet - so this gives it all.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim aLists  As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '//Find lists in the this workbook.
    aLists = FindRegionsInWorkbook(ThisWorkbook)

    For x = LBound(aLists) To UBound(aLists)
        Set rng = Range(aLists(x))
        Debug.Print rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address & _
            " | FirstCol: " & rng.Column & _
            " | LastCol: " & rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1 & _
            " | TopRow: " & rng.Row & _
            " | BottomRow: " & rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1 & _
            " | TotalRows: " & rng.Rows.Count & _
            " | TotalColumns: " & rng.Columns.Count
    Next x

    Debug.Assert False
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : FindRegionsInWorkbook
' Author    : Zack Barresse (MVP), Oregon, USA. (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=309052)
' Date      : 20/03/2008
' Purpose   : Returns each region in each worksheet within the workbook in the 'sRegion' variable.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function FindRegionsInWorkbook(wrkBk As Workbook) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rRegion As Range, sRegion As String, sCheck As String
    Dim sAddys As String, arrAddys() As String, aRegions() As Variant
    Dim iCnt As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    '//Cycle through each worksheet in workbook.
    j = 0
    For Each ws In wrkBk.Worksheets
        sAddys = vbNullString
        sRegion = vbNullString
        On Error Resume Next
        '//Find all ranges of constant & formula valies in worksheet.
        sAddys = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Address(0, 0) & ","
        sAddys = sAddys & ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Address(0, 0)
        If Right(sAddys, 1) = "," Then sAddys = Left(sAddys, Len(sAddys) - 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sAddys = vbNullString Then GoTo SkipWs
        '//Put each seperate range into an array.
        If InStr(1, sAddys, ",") = 0 Then
            ReDim arrAddys(0 To 0)
            arrAddys(0) = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & sAddys
        Else
            arrAddys = Split(sAddys, ",")
            For i = LBound(arrAddys) To UBound(arrAddys)
                arrAddys(i) = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & arrAddys(i)
            Next i
        End If
        '//Place region that range sits in into sRegion (if not already in there).
        For i = LBound(arrAddys) To UBound(arrAddys)
            If InStr(1, sRegion, ws.Range(arrAddys(i)).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)) = 0 Then
                sRegion = sRegion & ws.Range(arrAddys(i)).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0) & "," '*** no sheet
                sCheck = Right(arrAddys(i), Len(arrAddys(i)) - InStr(1, arrAddys(i), "!"))
                ReDim Preserve aRegions(0 To j)
                aRegions(j) = Left(arrAddys(i), InStr(1, arrAddys(i), "!") - 1) & "!" & ws.Range(sCheck).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
SkipWs:
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    FindRegionsInWorkbook = aRegions
    Exit Function
ErrHandle:
    'things you might want done if no lists were found...
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is an alternative to other answers:

```
intCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("a2").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
```

This will give you a *number of columns* while other answers will return a *column number*. Note that CurrentRegion will not include cells to the right of an empty column, or below an empty row. CHoice is yours depending on the requirements.

@Martin Dreher response is a perfect generic answer, with a small drawback: if you clear ranges to the right of the sheet, UsedRange might not be reset until you close/reopen the workbook.

@Jordan seems a good answer too, IF you know which row is the widest.